# Biblatex / MLA for official reports and websites

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, mla-style

I'm writing an thesis in British architecture and I need to follow the MLA style for bibliography.

I'm now using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [`biblatex-mla`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex-mla.html); but I can't find out how to define official reports (published by gov., commissions, associations, ...) or and web sites references (when it's not an article but just from the main website)

I can't find any clue in the two documentations.

EDIT: `biblatex-mla` adds restrictions to `biblatex`, so `@misc`, `@online` and `@report` are not written in the output file

Comment: I take it that the `report` and `online` types are in some way defective for your purpose?

Comment: Removed the `bibtex` tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ah, I see (from the edit) that there is an issue with `report` and `online`. I suspect this might be one for the author of `biblatex-mla`, as he may have had some reason for this.

Comment: I contacted the author of `biblatex-mla`, but did not receive any answer so far ...

Comment: I need to be able to cite an online source using biblatex-mla. Did the author ever give an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see this question, or I would have responded earlier. Many apologies.

At the moment, both "report" and "online" are undefined by biblatex-mla. For all of my own needs, I've never previously cited a website that couldn't be conceived of as an article, but I can see the worth. "Online," at least, could very easily be defined in the next version of biblatex-mla.

"Report" is another problem altogether. The MLA conceives of governmental authorship as if it were a nesting doll. Something by the "Department of Unusual Citations" in the US Senate would be cited like this:

United States. Cong. Senate. Dept. of Unusual Citations. Italicized Title. Washington: GPO, 2011. Print.

The next entry, by the House's "Bureau of Oddities" would look like this:

---.---. House. Bureau of Oddities. Italicized Title. Washington: GPO, 2011. Print.

You can see where things start becoming too much to handle. If Biblatex-mla is able to handle everything else you need, at the moment I'd recommend defining your report as a "book" with the author in your .bib file defined within curled braces. I don't want to release support for governmental publications unless I can do it correctly, that way my users understand the limitations of the software. With the recent innovations in Biblatex and Biber, I'll be looking closer at this problem to see if it's one I'll soon be able to solve.

Comment: See [my comment in another thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85698/can-biblatex-mla-support-online-entries/104123#104123) for an update on the `@online` entry type in Biblatex-mla. Unfortunately, @report remains an elusive beast.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the `biblatex` documentation, it says that there is an `online` type (like the `book` type you could use for web site referernces. It also has a `url` field.

Regarding the official reports, you could just use the `misc` type and fill its `howpublished` field.

Comment: Drat, didn't see your answer when posting.

Answer (score 0):

For web site references, the `@misc` type might be sufficient. This is for example what Wikipedia suggests when you click "Cite Page":

```
 @misc{ wiki:xxx,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title = "BibTeX --- Wikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
   year = "2010",
   url = "\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=BibTeX&oldid=379386079}",
   note = "[Online; accessed 19-August-2010]"
 }
```

Comment: The question is about `biblatex`, not plain bibtex.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Sorry. Should I remove answer?