# Misc entry not appearing in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-mla

I'm trying to add a misc entry to my bibliography, and despite biblatex recognizing the citation and citing it in-line, it refuses to put it into the works cited section:

(essay.tex)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{essay.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \autocite{misc}.

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(essay.bib)

```
@misc {misc,
    author = "Test author",
    title = "Test citation",
    publisher = "Publisher",
    year = "2005"}
```

The citation will show inline properly (`Test (author)`), but the entry doesn't appear in the bibliography. No errors or warnings are encountered when building with latex+biber+latex+latex.

Comment: I do not have the specified style. Without the style, I get the bibliography as expected (biblatex v3.3, biber 2.4).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2050/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160158/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85698/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369696/35864

Comment: This could probably seen as duplicate of [BibLaTex shows only book references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369696/35864)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me—had I seen the other questions in my searching, I wouldn't have had to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biblatex-mla` doesn't (yet) support a `misc` entry type (the following is quoted from `mla-new.bbx`):

> `% drivers to add eventually:
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{artwork}
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{audio}
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{image}
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{movie}
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{music}
>   % * \DeclareBibliographyDriver{performance}`

Furthermore, it somewhat oddly sets aliases for these type to `customa` but doesn't provide a bibliography driver for the `customa` entry type, so nothing gets printed.

As a partial solution, you can reassign the alias to some existing entry type for which there is a driver. In this example, I've set it to be formatted like an article.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{misc,
    author = "Author, Test",
    title = "Test Title",
    publisher = "Publisher",
    year = "2005"}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{misc}{article}

\begin{document}

Test \autocite{misc}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]