# Use `misc` in biblatex-mla

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I've narrowed down my problem to the use of `\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}`, which apparently [disallows the `@misc` type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2050/37357). The citations are correctly generated but do not appear in the output.

How can I use a `misc` type with MLA style and have it printed in the output? Specifically, how can I cite a personal interview and a web site? `misc` seems to be the accepted way for both of these.

I've provided a MWE below. Am I missing something obvious?

---

Addendum:

For websites I've looked at the (non-standard) `electronic`, but it doesn't look like I can specify a website name. The output I get is of the form

> "Webpage title." 2013. 12 February 2014. <http://www.example.com/>.

which is good but I need "*Foobar Corporation*" in between the title and the year of publication. Using `author` places the author before the title.

---

### MWE

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{foo}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**test.bib**

```
@MISC{foo,
  author = {Jones, Bob},
  title = {Personal interview},
  howpublished = {personal interview},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013}
}
@ELECTRONIC{bar,
  year = {2013},
  title = {Webpage title},
  note = {12 February 2014}, % this feels hackish already
  url = {http://www.example.com/}
  % how do I do "publisher = {Foobar Corporation}" ?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `MISC`, you can use the `UNPUBLISHED` type. For a website you could use `ONLINE`:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@UNPUBLISHED{foo,
  author = {Jones, Bob},
  title = {Personal interview},
  howpublished = {personal interview},
  date = {2013}
}

@ONLINE{ctan,
  author        = {CTAN},
  title     = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  date         = 2006,
  url          = {http://www.ctan.org},
  urldate      = {2006-10-01},
  label        = {CTAN},
}

@ONLINE{ctani,
  title        = {CTAN},
  date         = 2006,
  url          = {http://www.ctan.org},
  subtitle     = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  urldate      = {2006-10-01},
  label        = {CTAN},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works for interviews. Do you have any recommendations for web URLs? (UNPUBLISHED feels wrong because they're ... well, public. ELECTRONIC doesn't allow me to specify the web site name.)

Comment: @WChargin There's an `ONLINE` type. For example, `@ONLINE{ctan,
  title        = {CTAN},
  date         = 2006,
  url          = {http://www.ctan.org},
  subtitle     = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  urldate      = {2006-10-01},
  label        = {CTAN},
}`

Comment: Close, but that gives `"CTAN: The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network"` instead of `"CTAN." The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network.` Is there a different field I should use instead of `subtitle`? The `label` field doesn't seem to appear at all.

Comment: @WChargin you can (ab)use some available field: `@ONLINE{ctan,
  author        = {CTAN},
  date         = 2006,
  url          = {http://www.ctan.org},
  title     = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  urldate      = {2006-10-01},
  label        = {CTAN},
}`

Comment: okay; I guess that's close enough. I would have preferred the site name to come [after the title](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/08/) but that's okay. Thanks for your help.