# Bibliography is empty

Tags: biblatex, biber

I've read most of the other posts on this, but their errors/solutions aren't the same and don't seem to work. Maybe I just need a simple explanation. Anyways,

Here goes:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

%bibliography
\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mli.bib}

%.bib file
\begin{filecontents*}{mli.bib}
@misc{ dream,
             keywords = {trans},
             title = { Dr{\"o}mde mig en dr{\"o}m i natt}, 
             url = {http://www.folkwiki.se/Musik/1890}, 
             journal = {FolkWiki}
}

@misc{ midna,
             keywords = {trans},
             title = {Midna's Lament}, 
             url = {https://www.ninsheetmusic.org/browse/series/TheLegendofZelda}, 
             journal = {The Legend of Zelda - NinSheetMusic},
             author = {Erich}, 
             year = {2006}
}

@misc{ polska,
             keywords = {trans},
             title = {Polska efter Pelle Fors}, 
             url = {http://www.folkwiki.se/Musik/860}, 
             journal = {FolkWiki}
}


\end{filecontents*}

\title{blah}

\author{me}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[keyword = trans]{Transcriptions}

\end{document}
```

MikTex 2.9, I just updated most packages to resolve this issue, I know to run `pdflatex` then `biber` then `pdflatex` twice

I get the following issues [paraphrasing because it still produces a pdf without leaving the error list visible]:

- hyperref package is missing, setting hyperref = false
- keyword trans not found
- empty bibliography

(and I'm using keywords because I have more bibliographies for other sections)

I'd appreciate any help!

p.s. Also quick question. How to cite songs in MLA using the `.bib` file (like with albums and stuff)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MWE no entries were cited. `biblatex` only shows entries in the bibliography if they were `\cite`d explicitly or if they were added to the bibliography with `\nocite` (either via a blanket `\nocite{*}` that adds all entries available in the `.bib` files or a specific `\nocite{key_1,...,key_n}`). See [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864).

The second issue is that `biblatex-mla` has no code set up to display `@misc` sources. The way the style handles these unsupported types means that there is not even the usual warning that `biblatex` would issue. See [Use `misc` in biblatex-mla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160158/35864), [Misc entry not appearing in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377460/35864), [BibLaTex shows only book references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369696/35864) and a few more.

The following MWE gives slightly better results. If you don't have to follow MLA style I would recommend not to use `biblatex-mla` until its development is picked up again and this particularity is resolved (in https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/issues/7#issuecomment-52112933 the `biblatex-mla` developers explains his reasoning for not supporting `@misc`, but I think the way the support is disabled is quite dangerous, there is no warning or error message).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{dream,
  keywords = {trans},
  title    = {Dr{\"o}mde mig en dr{\"o}m i natt}, 
  url      = {http://www.folkwiki.se/Musik/1890}, 
  journal  = {FolkWiki},
}
@online{midna,
  keywords = {trans},
  title    = {Midna's Lament}, 
  url      = {https://www.ninsheetmusic.org/browse/series/TheLegendofZelda}, 
  journal  = {The Legend of Zelda - NinSheetMusic},
  author   = {Erich}, 
  year     = {2006},
}
@online{polska,
  keywords = {trans},
  title    = {Polska efter Pelle Fors}, 
  url      = {http://www.folkwiki.se/Musik/860}, 
  journal  = {FolkWiki},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography[keyword = trans, title={Transcriptions}]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\printbibliography[keyword = trans]{Transcriptions}` does not print the bibliography with the heading *Transcriptions*, it just prints the bibliography and after that the word *Transcriptions*.